# how to make Google sheets REGEXREPLACE return empty string if it fails?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I'm using the REGEXREPLACE function in google sheets to extract some text contained in skus. If it doesn't find a text, it seems to return the entire original string. Is it possible to make it return an empty string instead? Having problems with this because it doesn't actually error out, so using iserror doesn't seem to work.

Example: my sku SHOULD contain 5 separate groups delimited by the underscore character '_'. in this example it is missing the last group, so it returns the entire original string.

LDSS0107_SS-WH_5
=REGEXREPLACE($A3,"[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_(.*)","$1")

Fails to find the fifth capture group, that is correct... but I need it to give me an empty string when it fails... presently gives me the whole original string. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the solution would be to add the missing groups:

```
=REGEXREPLACE($A1&REPT("_ ",4-(LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_","")))),"[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_(.*)","$1")
```

This returns space as result for missing group. If you don't want to, use `TRIM` function.

[image]